# Method replacements for material ui v4 to v5 upgrade

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently migrating from v4 to v5, but it appears `@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator` wasn't carried over or is accessible differently. I tried to find info about it in the docs and migration guide but didn't see anything. Is there an alternative that should be usied to access methods such as `darken()`? also i'm looking for the alternative to getting styles from things i.e. `import { styles as FabStyles } from "@material-ui/core/Fab/Fab";` in v5. I don't see away to access the individual styles now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`darken`, `lighten`, `alpha`, and other functions accessed via `@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator` in v4 are [exported](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.1/packages/mui-material/src/styles/index.js#L12) from `@mui/material/styles` in v5.

Though the migration guide doesn't explicitly mention it, at least some cases of this are handled by the [preset-safe codemod](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#preset-safe) (specifically the [core-styles-import codemod](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.1/packages/mui-codemod/src/v5.0.0/core-styles-import.js)).

Here's an example usage of `darken` in v5:

```
import { darken } from "@mui/material/styles";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ color: "#f00" }}>#f00</h1>
      <h1 style={{ color: darken("#f00", 0.25) }}>darken("#f00", 0.25)</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit darken]

As far as the last portion of your question, the styles for each component are no longer exported separately and cannot be leveraged independent of the component.

Comment: Do yo know by any chance what happend to the `colorManipulator`'s `fade()` method?
E: Nvm, seems to be renamed to `alpha()`.